# my paystack payment gateway popup is not showing/poping up

Tags: javascript, android, webview, popup

This code is not working and my paystack payment gateway is not showing, though it displays the spinner but will not show the form for card input.
Please I need a complete code that will help me get my job done:

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
            boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {



            WebView newWebView = new WebView(WebpageActivity.this);
            newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            view.addView(newWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this code should work when pasted on your MainActivity file of your android webview project.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


        WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.your_url.com/");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

        private Activity activity = null;

        public WebViewClientImpl(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
            if(url.indexOf("your_url") > -1 ) return false;

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Now, after pasting the above code you need to use the PHP paystack integration this time and not the javascript paystack integration initialization and callback functions.
At this point you only need to worry about your sessions.

Tested And Confirmed.